# Use linq to map parent child structure

Tags: c#, linq

I have the domain classes separated from the ones I use in the views, so when retrieving data I have to map the domain classes to the view ones.
Until now this have been straight forward, but now I have a case in which I need to map parent-child classes from the domain to parent-child classes on the view.

Using `foreach` structures works fine, but I have quite a few linq methods that do the mapping between domain and view classes, that need to be refactored to accomodated to the new requirements and would be faster if I knew how to do it with linq. Thanks in advance.

As an example of what I'm trying to accomplish see code below:

In the repository I have the classes:

```
    public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
};

public class ChildA : Parent
{
    public string ChildPropertyA { get; set; }
};

public class ChildB : Parent
{
    public string ChildPropertyB { get; set; }
};
```

Then in the UI I have the classes:

```
    public class ParentVM
{
    public int ParentIdVM { get; set; }
    public string ParentNameVM { get; set; }
};

public class ChildAVM : ParentVM
{
    public string ChildPropertyAVM { get; set; }
};

public class ChildBVM : ParentVM
{
    public string ChildPropertyBVM { get; set; }
};
```

Now I will have a service class in which the methods will look like the one below:

```
        public GetParentVMs()
    {
        var parents = initializeRepositoryClass();

        var parentsVM = MapRepositoryToViewClasses(parents);

        ShowResult(parentsVM);
    }
```

Where:

```
        public List<Parent> initializeRepositoryClass()
    {
        var parents = new List<Parent>(){
            new ChildA(){ParentId=1, ParentName="Parent 1", ChildPropertyA="A"},
            new Parent(){ParentId=2, ParentName="Parent 2"},
            new ChildB(){ParentId=3, ParentName="Parent 3", ChildPropertyB="B"},
        };
        return parents;
    }
    private List<ParentVM> MapRepositoryToViewClasses(List<Parent> parents)
    {
        var parentsVM = new List<ParentVM>();
        foreach (var item in parents)
        {
            if (item is ChildA)
            {
                var itemVM = item as ChildA;
                parentsVM.Add(
                    new ChildAVM() { ParentIdVM = itemVM.ParentId, ParentNameVM = itemVM.ParentName, ChildPropertyAVM = itemVM.ChildPropertyA }
                );
            }
            else if (item is ChildB)
            {
                var itemVM = item as ChildB;
                parentsVM.Add(
                new ChildBVM() { ParentIdVM = itemVM.ParentId, ParentNameVM = itemVM.ParentName, ChildPropertyBVM = itemVM.ChildPropertyB }
                );
            }
            else
            {
                var itemVM = item as Parent;
                parentsVM.Add(
                new ParentVM() { ParentIdVM = itemVM.ParentId, ParentNameVM = itemVM.ParentName }
                );
            }
        }
        return parentsVM;
    }
    private void ShowResult(List<ParentVM> parentsVM)
    {
        foreach (var item in parentsVM)
        {
            if (item is ChildAVM)
            {
                var ca = (ChildAVM)item;
                Console.WriteLine("Child A " + ca.ChildPropertyAVM);
            }
            else if (item is ChildBVM)
            {
                var cb = (ChildBVM)item;
                Console.WriteLine("Child B " + cb.ChildPropertyBVM);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Parent ");
            }
        }
    }
```

The code above will work, but I like to change the method MapRepositoryToViewClasses to another that uses linq, and looks a like the one below:

```
        private List<ParentVM> MapRepositoryToViewClassesLinq(List<Parent> parents)
    {
        var parentsVM =
            from p in parents 
                case
                    p is ChildA then select new ChildAVM() {ChildPropertyAVM = p.ChildPropertyA, ...};
                else
                    p is ChildB then select new ChildBVM() {ChildPropertyBVM = p.ChildPropertyB, ...};
                else
                    select new ParentVM() {ParentIdVM = p.ParentId};


    return parentsVM.ToList();
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some changes in your code to make it better

1) You have to introduce a factory to create VM's instances.

```
class VMFactory
{
    public ParentVM Create(Parent obj)
    {
        var childA = obj as ChildA;
        if (childA != null)
        {
            return new ChildAVM() { ParentIdVM = childA.ParentId, ParentNameVM = childA.ParentName, ChildPropertyAVM = childA .ChildPropertyA };
        }

        var childB = obj as ChildB;
        if(childB != null)
        {
                return new ChildBVM() { ParentIdVM = childB.ParentId, ParentNameVM = childB.ParentName, ChildPropertyBVM = childB.ChildPropertyB };
        }

        return new ParentVM() { ParentIdVM = obj.ParentId, ParentNameVM = obj.ParentName };
    }
}
```

2) Now you can simplify your code at MapRepositoryToViewClasses method

```
private List<ParentVM> MapRepositoryToViewClasses(List<Parent> parents)
{
    // Factory instance can be provided by the outer scope
    var factory = new VMFactory();
    var parentsVM = new List<ParentVM>();
    foreach (var item in parents)
    {
        parentsVM.Add(factory.Create(item));
    }

    return parentsVM;
}
```

3) Final step, let's use Linq to map

```
private List<ParentVM> MapRepositoryToViewClasses(List<Parent> parents)
{
    // Factory instance can be provided by the outer scope
    var factory = new VMFactory();

    return parents.Select(factory.Create).ToList();
}
```

It's done

---

Yet another attempt to solve it

1) Create the extensions to solve common tasks.

```
static class Ext
{
    public static ParentVM Map<TIn>(this TIn obj, Func<TIn, ParentVM> func)
        where TIn : Parent
    {
        var source = obj as TIn;
        return source != null
            ? func(obj)
            : null;
    }
}
```

2) Use the extension method to get VMs

```
private List<ParentVM> MapRepositoryToViewClassesLinq(List<Parent> parents)
{
    var tmp = from p in parents
              select
                  p.Map<ChildA>(c => new ChildAVM() { ParentIdVM = c.ParentId, ParentNameVM = c.ParentName, ChildPropertyAVM = c.ChildPropertyA }) ??
                  p.Map<ChildB>(c => new ChildBVM() { ParentIdVM = c.ParentId, ParentNameVM = c.ParentName, ChildPropertyBVM = c.ChildPropertyB }) ??
                  new ParentVM() { ParentIdVM = obj.ParentId, ParentNameVM = obj.ParentName };

    return tmp.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Nice answer but I have dozens of methods that use a mapping like: from p in parents select new parentVM(){...} and I want to avoid a big refactor. Is there a way to substitute the new parentVM(){} for something like new factory.create??. Thanks

Comment: What I'm really looking for, is something with a syntax like the one I show in method MapRepositoryToViewClassesLinq. The classes that are already mapped on my project use similar syntax(without inheritance), and I'm wondering if there is some way to do that with linq without rewriting the entire method.

Comment: It not so easy to provide a nice solution without refactoring, I'll try to show another one.

Answer (score 1):

If you setup mapping extensions for each type, then the mapping process becomes trivial.

**SQL Fiddle:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/a4eQ6S

**How to map (`GetParentsVM()`)**

```
var parents = initializeRepositoryClass();
var parentsVM = parents.Map();
```

**Mapping Extensions**

```
public static class ParentMappings
{
    public static ChildAVM Map(this ChildA model)
    {
        return new ChildAVM()
            {
                ParentIdVM = model.ParentId,
                ParentNameVM = model.ParentName,
                ChildPropertyAVM = model.ChildPropertyA,
            };
    }
    public static ChildBVM Map(this ChildB model)
    {
        return new ChildBVM()
            {
                ParentIdVM = model.ParentId,
                ParentNameVM = model.ParentName,
                ChildPropertyBVM = model.ChildPropertyB,
            };
    }
    public static ParentVM Map(this Parent model)
    {
        if (model is ChildA)
            return ((ChildA)model).Map();
        else if (model is ChildB)
            return ((ChildB)model).Map();
        else
            return new ParentVM()
                {
                    ParentIdVM = model.ParentId,
                    ParentNameVM = model.ParentName,
                };
    }
    public static List<ParentVM> Map(this List<Parent> parents)
    {
        return parents.Select(p => p.Map()).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is a nice approach but doesn't solve my problem, which in this case is to avoid a big refactor of existing mappings done with linq. But I may use this in the future. Thanks

Comment: Check out Automapper. If you're member/property names matched, you can use it to automatically go between the objects. I didn't put it in the answer since your property names are different, so you have to map the property names from and to somewhere, so it didn't really help.